# P5JS: How to make the background image repeat?

Tags: html, web, p5.js, game-development

So I've been struggling with this for a lot of time, I'll keep it short.

I'm working on my first P5JS game, and it's like Mario, but instead of horizontal endless runner, its vertical. So, I added an image as the background like this **in setup function:**

```
bg=createSprite(300,300);
```

and **in the draw function:**

```
background("black"); 
bg.addImage(bgImage);
bg.velocityY=5;
```

The velocityY constantly makes the image move downwards, but because it is an image, after a while the black background comes up again.
Like so:(the road is the image and the black color is the background.)

[image]

So how do I make it so that after the image has gone away, it comes back in, and it seems like it never even left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could have two images, whenever one is fully invisible `(img.y < height)`
just teleport it back up to the top `img.y = img2.y - img.height`.

Also i believe that's the math to do so, but i'm not completely sure about it.

Also there might be a function for tiling in the library.

Comment: Yeah, there's no function like that, but your solution seems to work.